# save the transient instance before flushing : com.bookstore.domain.security.UserRole.role -> com.bookstore.domain.security.Role

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'm following a tutorial about spring boot ..
I got this error : 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.bookstore.domain.security.UserRole.role -> com.bookstore.domain.security.Role

User.java

```
package com.bookstore.domain;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.bookstore.domain.security.Authority;
import com.bookstore.domain.security.UserRole;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private boolean enabled=true;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserShipping> userShippingList;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserPayment> userPaymentList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Order> orderList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }
    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }



    public List<UserShipping> getUserShippingList() {
        return userShippingList;
    }
    public void setUserShippingList(List<UserShipping> userShippingList) {
        this.userShippingList = userShippingList;
    }
    public List<UserPayment> getUserPaymentList() {
        return userPaymentList;
    }
    public void setUserPaymentList(List<UserPayment> userPaymentList) {
        this.userPaymentList = userPaymentList;
    }

    public ShoppingCart getShoppingCart() {
        return shoppingCart;
    }
    public void setShoppingCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart) {
        this.shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrderList() {
        return orderList;
    }
    public void setOrderList(List<Order> orderList) {
        this.orderList = orderList;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorites = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.forEach(ur -> authorites.add(new Authority(ur.getRole().getName())));

        return authorites;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }


}
```

Role.java

```
package com.bookstore.domain.security;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    private int roleId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    public int getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }


}
```

UserRole.java

```
package com.bookstore.domain.security;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.bookstore.domain.User;

@Entity
@Table(name="user_role")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userRoleId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    private Role role;

    public UserRole(){}

    public UserRole(User user, Role role) {
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
    }


    public Long getUserRoleId() {
        return userRoleId;
    }


    public void setUserRoleId(Long userRoleId) {
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
    }


    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }


    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }


    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


}

BookstoreApplication.java

package com.bookstore;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.bookstore.domain.User;
import com.bookstore.domain.security.Role;
import com.bookstore.domain.security.UserRole;
import com.bookstore.service.UserService;
import com.bookstore.utility.SecurityUtility;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BookstoreApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookstoreApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setFirstName("John");
        user1.setLastName("Adams");
        user1.setUsername("j");
        user1.setPassword(SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder().encode("p"));
        user1.setEmail("JAdams@gmail.com");
        Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
        Role role1= new Role();
        role1.setRoleId(1);
        role1.setName("ROLE_USER");
        userRoles.add(new UserRole(user1, role1));

        userService.createUser(user1, userRoles);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try using CascadeType.MERGE in User class in "Set<UserRole> userRoles" field.

Comment: Yessss !Thank you Ashutosh ! it works ! thanks to :  "Set<UserRole> userRoles"